# How to see the logs of api hits when using pm2 server start

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am new to node js and pm2. I use pm2 to run the application in background. How can view all the api hits(200,400) and stuff that is seen on console when running the app in local. I have tried pm2 logs and other commands but they don't show any api hits and stuff. Pls help me in that.

Comment: How to run the static files in the server after deployment of the application. After serving the static files the javascript files are shown with html text. How to fix it.

Comment: in order to log requests, you have to configure logging in your app itself. pm2 will show whatever your application logs

Answer (score 4):

PM2 will display whatever is console logged by nodejs. There is a specific library which will do this automatically for you and is called "morgan".

https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

You just need to install it with npm from terminal:

```
sudo npm install --save morgan
```

in your server file:

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

and then in terminal:

```
sudo pm2 restart server;
sudo pm2 logs;
```

should do the trick.

Sorry if there are any mistakes in my mini tutorial but I have provided you with the "morgan" module documentation so you should manage to fix any mistakes.